# Multiple login entities and Multiple level access permission in ASP.NET MVC-5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I'm building a system where have 4 level login,
there is 4 Entities involved.

1. System owner
2. Distributor
3. Agent
4. Subagent

System owner can create distributor login, distributor create agent login and agent create subagent login.

I have created 4 projects, each has their own login identity. But the problem is I cannot create Distributor login details from System Owner project.
Do I need to merge all projects into 1? If yes, how can i separate these login for each entity?

any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Use claims to define the account type.  See this article as an example: http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com.au/2013/12/using-claims-in-aspnet-identity.html

Comment: @BrendanGreen thanks, let me read the article first

Comment: @User2012384 nope, I'm Chinese Indonesian

Comment: Use Roles. You can define a Role for a User or multiple Roles and include logic that provides different content to different Roles

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create four separate projects for each user. You can make this with in a single project.

You can manage pages and functionalities for each user type using Microsoft ASP.Net Identity 2.

I can explain the basic idea to do this.

**Step 1**

Create four **Roles** for each user.

**Step 2**

Create a same login page for all users.

**Step 3**

When a user login, identify his/ her role in our system.

**Step 4**

Redirect to home page based on logged in user's role.

**Step 5**

Dynamically generate menu for each user.

**Step 6**

Authenticate each functionality based on logged in user's roles.

That's it !!!

Answer (score 0):

I created 5 Projects

1. Class Library for all Entities(include 4 Class LogIn Entities, SignInManager, User Manager and DbContext)
2. System Owner Project
3. Distributor Project
4. Agent Project
5. Subagent Project

Note:
I design the Class Library this way to make sure we can use migration

I was using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity version 2. There was a bugs on IdentityDbContext.ValidateEntity method which it will check unique rule for UserName in table AspNetUsers.
(Because checking against AspNetUsers table will cause error when there is same username or email between Different EntitySet inherit from IdentityUser)

At the end, I inherit directly from DbContext class and put Identity Classes there. Also delete the ValidateEntity method there

Here is my Context Class code:

```
public partial class MyDbContext: DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext() : base("name=MyDbContext") { }
    public static MyDbContext Create()
    {
        return new MyDbContext();
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

        // Needed to ensure subclasses share the same table
        var user = modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>()
            .ToTable("Users");
        user.HasMany(u => u.Roles).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId);
        user.HasMany(u => u.Claims).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(uc => uc.UserId);
        user.HasMany(u => u.Logins).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(ul => ul.UserId);
        user.Property(u => u.UserName)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(256)
            .HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("UserNameIndex") { IsUnique = false })); // Unique False because there might have same UserName between EntitySet

        // CONSIDER: u.Email is Required if set on options?
        user.Property(u => u.Email).HasMaxLength(256);

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>()
            .HasKey(r => new { r.UserId, r.RoleId })
            .ToTable("UserRoles");

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>()
            .HasKey(l => new { l.LoginProvider, l.ProviderKey, l.UserId })
            .ToTable("UserLogins");

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>()
            .ToTable("UserClaims");

        var role = modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>()
            .ToTable("Roles");
        role.Property(r => r.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(256)
            .HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("RoleNameIndex") { IsUnique = false }));
        role.HasMany(r => r.Users).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<SystemOwnerApplicationUser>().ToTable("SystemOwnerApplicationUsers");
        modelBuilder.Entity<DistributorApplicationUser>().ToTable("DistributorApplicationUsers");
        modelBuilder.Entity<AgentApplicationUser>().ToTable("AgentApplicationUsers");
        modelBuilder.Entity<SubagentApplicationUser>().ToTable("SubagentApplicationUsers");
    }

    public virtual DbSet<SystemOwnerApplicationUser> SystemOwnerApplicationUsers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<DistributorApplicationUser> DistributorApplicationUsers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AgentApplicationUser> AgentApplicationUsers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<SubagentApplicationUser> SubagentApplicationUsers { get; set; }
}
```

Creating user between project can be done by this way

```
            if (!(context.DistributorApplicationUsers.Any(u => u.UserName == userName)))
            {
                var userStore = new UserStore<DistributorApplicationUser>(context);
                var userManager = new DistributorApplicationUserManager(userStore);
                var userToInsert = new DistributorApplicationUser { UserName = userName, Email = email, EmailConfirmed = true, Distributor = distributor };
                IdentityResult result = userManager.Create(userToInsert, password);
            }
            if (!(context.AgentApplicationUsers.Any(u => u.UserName == userName)))
            {
                var userStore = new UserStore<AgentApplicationUser>(context);
                var userManager = new AgentApplicationUserManager(userStore);
                var userToInsert = new AgentApplicationUser { UserName = userName, Email = email, EmailConfirmed = true, Agent = agent };
                IdentityResult result = userManager.Create(userToInsert, password);
            }
            if (!(context.SubagentApplicationUsers.Any(u => u.UserName == userName)))
            {
                var userStore = new UserStore<SubagentApplicationUser>(context);
                var userManager = new SubagentApplicationUserManager(userStore);
                var userToInsert = new SubagentApplicationUser { UserName = userName, Email = email, EmailConfirmed = true, Subagent = subagent };
                IdentityResult result = userManager.Create(userToInsert, password);
            }
```